Root Extractor circuit

I'm currently building a root extractor circuit in LTspice following this schematic provided in the link given below but instead using ADTL084 opamp: https://usermanual.wiki/Document/snla140b.1643036625/view.
However, there are no explanation provided for this schematic. Can anyone explain to me the mechanism of this circuit and provide any equation necessary to calculate the resistance and capacitance used here?

Start by supposing that the input is zero volts. Can you follow through some chain of logic from there? What current must be pulled via Q1's emitter? What does this mean for the anode voltage of D1 and emitter voltage of Q2? Etc? I've only glanced at this and I'm not confirming its function. But I want to see how you approach it.

As it is a "root extractor" based on "log/antilog" circuit, use 1 volt at the input. Should be better than 0V. C1, C2 and C3 are for "compensation". Should not be used with "modern" opamps.

There's a detailed explanation of how that that works in one of the early Op Amp application notes from the old National Semiconductor Corporation, AN-4.  It was written by Robert C. Widlar, one of the early geniuses in op amp design back in 1968.  You may be able to find it or something similar on the TI site.

In fact, the schematic you show is identical to figure 11 in the above mentioned ap note.

Looks like Exp ( 0.5 * Log (Vin) ) === Vin^0.5 cirquit.

@SteveSh Thanks for helping the questioner with that link. It makes me sad and happy at the same time. Much education in application notes have been stripped away as time passes, not only including the excellent explanations by extremely good educators but also their very names have been stripped away from history. "It's just business" isn't an excuse. Rather, it's vile. To take a parallel from a different field some of the very best teaching materials on operating system design and nuanced concepts such as coroutines were written in the PDP databooks from late 1960's and early 1970's. Gone.

Jackson, there's not been the slightest word from you. Not so much as a peep. Instead, yet another question. And there? Not a peep. This isn't acceptable. Help us to help you. Have a look at the application note that @SteveSh points out to you. And write something. The topic is interesting and worth a moment and I'm sure that good questions from you will get good answers. Put some effort in -- after all, this is your life and your question and aren't you worthy of your own efforts?

As it is a "root extractor" based on "log/antilog" circuit, use 1 volt at the input.
Should be better than 0V. The resistors are the same.
V5 and R16 linearize the "curve" at the lower scales.
R12 and R13 "scales" the curve at the right.
X1 makes the "log" function. X2 makes the "1/2" function. X3 makes the "anti-log" function.
Made with microcap v12

