Square law conversion analog circuit using log and antilog amplifier

My approach to performing a circuit that could square root the input is to use a combination of log amplifier > inverting amplifier > exponential amplifier > inverting amplifier. The 2nd inverting amplifier gain is set to 2 because if I try to set it to 0.5 ((ln(input))^0.5), the voltage would be too low to pass through the transistor connecting to the exponential circuit. Hence I place the gain to be 2 and scale it down to 0.5 by setting the gain to 0.25 at the last inverting amplifier.
The output is not as expected when I tried it with DC, sine or triangular input. What modification should I make here if I want to retain my approach using log and antilog amplifier circuit?

Note that the input must be "STRICTLY" positive ... https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/714343/root-extractor-circuit

Your circuit computes
$$0.25e^{2\ln(V_2)} = 0.25 V_2^2$$
which doesn't sound like what you intended. Multiplication in the log domain is equivalent to raising to a power in the linear domain. You can't expect to just scale things up in one domain and compensate for that in the other.
