Variable Analog Multiplier (Resistor Values, Concepts)
Is there a way to create a variable analog multiplier using conventional op amps? I've been trying to wrap my head around analog multipliers, and I haven't been able to come up with a reliable answer for this. Here's the basic schematic:

The way I understand it is that R1 and R2  (and accompanying op amps and diodes) are your input log amplifiers, while R3, R4, and R5 form a summing amplifier, and the last op amp (with diode and R6) form an antilog amplifier.
From what I've read, the main relationship is between the values of R1 and R2, but is it possible to use a potentiometer as a variable resistor for R2's "X" value? For example, if I want to be able to multiply V1's resistance by 1x-10x, would a 10K potentiometer work here, or am I misinterpreting the concept and that would be multiplying R1's value by 1K-10K instead of 1x-10x?
I also know that some implementations of multiplier amps call for NPN resistors in lieu of the diodes for temperature compensation - is this something that should be considered here?

Why wouldn't a potentiometer work? Just connect it as a variable resistor.

@Hearth that's basically what I wanted to know ha, it seems obvious, but I just didn't know if there was a fundamental principal I was missing with the way the circuit works. Would I need to scale R1 to compensate for the potentiometer value, or would 1K for R1 and R2 being a 10K pot yield the assumed 1x-10x in the original post?

Why not use a simulator and find out.

FYI, often a diode connected BJT is used instead of a standard diode. They are often more "ideal" in their characteristics than diodes made for rectifying signals or power.

Try to fix V1 and V2 which must be "positive" ... For example V1=10 V and V2= 10 V. Then V1= 10 V and V2= 1 V.

See this https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/714343/root-extractor-circuit for another circuit.


... but is it possible to use a potentiometer as a variable resistor for R2's "X" value?

The answer is no, because the "function" of the circuit is "shifted" ...
Here is the justification by simulation made with microcap v12.
The temperature is "fixed" to 27 °C.
This is a "logarithmic" circuit made with 5 decades voltage input.
It is adjusted with "offsets" and some values of resistors to be "ok".
NB: There is a "little" non-linearity on the beginning of the curve.

Here is what happens when you change the input R4 resistor value.
The changes occur on a restricted scale (between 0.1 V and 10 V, the more linear part).
You can see that the "logarithmic" output is changing a while.

And here what happens on the full input voltage scale.


Thank you for this (and the link to a related topic above). Is their any sort of circuit that could provide similar results to what I'm looking for? I've looked into four quadrant multipliers, etc., but I'm uncertain as to their efficacy given the parameters.

You have to define your inputs limits. Only after, you can make a choice for integrated multipliers or do it yourself.

Insofar as voltage and resistance (just want to make sure I'm understanding correctly)? Let's say 5V-0V, and resistance value let's arbitrarily say 8.2K (multiplied by 1x-10x). My initial idea was something of a resistance or current multiplier, but I was having difficulty finding exactly what I was looking for, so the blanket "analog multiplier" seemed like the best place to start.

You can start with https://www.analog.com/en/products/ad633.html <<<The AD633 is laser calibrated to a guaranteed total accuracy of 2% of full scale. Nonlinearity for the Y input is typically less than 0.1% and noise referred to the output is typically less than 100 μV rms in a 10 Hz to 10 kHz bandwidth. >>>
